# R - return datatable row number of max or min value in sliding window

Tags: r, max, row-number, sliding-window

I am trying to retrieve a row number associated with the max/min value in a sliding-window. I'm then subsetting that row number to retrieve a value from a different column.

Per your request, here is the dput(head(DATAFRAME3)):

```
structure(list(Time = c("00:00:01|", "00:00:03|", "00:00:04|", 
"00:00:05|", "00:00:06|", "00:00:07|"), Average = c(8, 5.75, 
5.33333333333333, 5.23076923076923, 5.15, 5.15), NegativeChange = c(-3, 
-0.75, -0.333333333333333, -0.230769230769231, -0.15, -0.15), 
    PositiveChange = c(0, 0, 0.107843137254902, 0.210407239819005, 
    0.291176470588235, 0.291176470588235)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Average", "NegativeChange", "PositiveChange"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000001300788>)
```

Here is an upload of a truncated text data file, and subsequently, the code I used to import it to R and get it to the point where I was trying to code the End Timestamp portion:

http://textuploader.com/5ymml

Code:

```
#prepare workspace...delete prior data and values
rm(list=ls())

#Load packages
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

#set working directory, setwd(filepath)
setwd()

#load fixed width data, n = 39
DATAFRAME <- read.fwf("Dataframe3_Truncated.txt", widths = c(9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), header = FALSE, sep = "\t", skip = 4, na.strings = c("-"))

#transform to data.table
DATAFRAME <- data.table(DATAFRAME)

#Calculate row averages, adding an "Average" column to the data set
DATAFRAME2 <- DATAFRAME[, .(Average = rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE)), "V1"]

#Calculate NegativeChange and PositiveChange using subscript method
NegativeChange <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME2))
PositiveChange <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME2))
for (i in 1:(nrow(DATAFRAME2)-90)) {
  y <- i
  x <- i+90
  NegativeChange[i] <- min(DATAFRAME2$Average[y:x]) - DATAFRAME2$Average[i]
  PositiveChange[i] <- max(DATAFRAME2$Average[y:x]) - DATAFRAME2$Average[i]
 }

#add NegativeChange and PositiveChange columns to datatable
DATAFRAME3 <- DATAFRAME2[, .(Time = as.character(V1), Average, NegativeChange, PositiveChange)]
DATAFRAME3
```

PositiveChange is the maximum positive deviation from Average[i] in [i:i + 90]. NegativeChange is the maximum negative deviation from Average[i] in [i:i + 90]. The EndTimestamp, and why I'm trying to find the row number for the Max/Min value, should be for **max** *the timestamp at which the Average is highest [i:i + 90]* and for **min** *the timestamp at which the Average is lowest [i:i + 90]*.  I tried to get the EndTimestamp feature to trigger only when PositiveChange >= 1, or NegativeChange <= -1.

Examples of the code I've tried to find the max value row number are below:

```
#which.max
EndTimestamp <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME3))
for (i in seq(nrow(DATAFRAME3))) {
  X <- (i + 1)
  y <- (i + 91)
  z <- (i)
  if (DATAFRAME3$PositiveChange[i] >= 1) {
    EndTimestamp[i] <- DATAFRAME3[(which.max(DATAFRAME3$Average[x:y]) + z), Time]
  } else {
    EndTimestamp[i] <- NA
  }
}  



#which
TimestampRowIndex <- c()
TimestampRowActual <- c()
EndTimestamp3 <- numeric(nrow(DATAFRAME3))
for (i in seq(nrow(DATAFRAME3))) {
  X <- (i + 1)
  y <- (i + 91)
  z <- (i)
  if (DATAFRAME3$PositiveChange[i] >= 1) {
    TimestampRowIndex <- append(TimestampRowIndex, which(DATAFRAME3$Average[x:y] == max(DATAFRAME3$Average[x:y])))
    TimestampRowActual <- TimestampRowIndex[length(TimestampRowIndex)] + z
    EndTimestamp3[i] <- DATAFRAME3[as.integer(TimestampRowActual), Time]
  } else {
    EndTimestamp3[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

Neither solution works for finding the max for PositiveChange >= 1, and seem to do worse when transformed to find the min for NegativeChange <= -1. Due to the nature of the data, sequential rows wherein the Average >= 1 should in most cases have the same End Timestamp. But the code above produces ascending timestamps. And at one point (rows 928 through 973) produces descending timestamps, which makes no sense.

I'm sure there is a simple answer, but being new to R and coding generally, I've spent hours trying to find it to no avail.

Also, the z variable is to correct for the fact that the which and which.max functions return an index value based on the range being examined (I think). So if the max value in 500:600 is in the 504 row of the datatable, the which functions will return a value of 4. Is there a way around that, so that it would return 504?

Suggestions? Happy to provide more info if needed.

Comment: Take a look at `cummax` and `cummin`?

Comment: Also, it is better if you post a sample of input data with the desired output. One can provide working code in response.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: To upload your data, paste the output of `dput(head(DATAFRAME3))` into your question

Comment: Check out `zoo::rollmax` (or just `rollapply`), perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was asked to boil down the last (and first) question I asked on this site, so I was perhaps a bit too conservative this time around. I've edited the above, and linked a text data file so that anyone kind enough to help me can reproduce everything up to the point where I am hung up. Hopefully the pendulum didn't swing too far in the other direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of your code, why do you need moving window aggregates? Maybe there is a data structure more suitable for your problem. However, using given data, I suggest the following:

"NegativeChange" is the minimum deviance from average in a given interval. This is per definition the minimum value per interval.
You are looking for minmal (maximal) values in an moving window. package RcppRoll provieds usefull functions for this task:

```
library(RcppRoll)
DATAFRAME2$min_Average = roll_minl(Average, 90)
DATAFRAME2$max_Average = roll_maxl(Average, 90)
```

In your next step you are trying to get the row number (or the position in the interval?) of min/max value per interval
If you need this information you probably have to use a loop.

```
#Calculate row averages, adding an "Average" column to the data set
DATAFRAME2 <- DATAFRAME[, .(Average = rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE)), "V1"]

# calculate min/max of rolling Window
for (i in 1:nrow(DATAFRAME2)) {
    j = min(i+90, nrow(DATAFRAME2)) # upper bound of window
    DATAFRAME2$min_Average[i] = min(DATAFRAME2$Average[i:j])
    DATAFRAME2$pos_min_Average[i] = (i-1) + which.min(DATAFRAME2$Average[i:j])
    DATAFRAME2$max_Average[i] = max(DATAFRAME2$Average[i:j])
    DATAFRAME2$pos_max_Average[i] = (i-1) + which.max(DATAFRAME2$Average[i:j])
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. Learned a few things in reviewing your solution, too. Much appreciated.